# How to zip directory excluding symbolic links and the files they point to?

Tags: linux, files, symlink, zip

I have a directory with files, subdirectories and symlinks

How to zip **only** files and folders from that directory without symlinks or files referred to by the symlink?

Comment: Do you mean store symlinks, but not files (instead of symlinks)?

Comment: Do you want the files the symlinks point to?

Comment: I'd rsync the directory into a sibling if possible, and hardlink the files (to reduce diskspace), then (depending on the version of rsync...) find/delete the symbolic links in the sibling directory, and zip/move the contents of the sibling directory (finish by removing the top-level sibling).

Comment: I want to zip only ordinary files and folders, not symlinks nor the files referred to by the symlink

Comment: You need zip -j to junk the paths

Answer (score 17):

use 'zip -y' option it copies the link as is, instead of the complete file.

Comment: The OP has said three times that they don’t want to get the links *at all,* so this seems to be wrong.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't answer the OP's question, but it does answer mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@exclude_file`: save the symlinks and their target paths<sup>1</sup> in a text file then zip the directory and use that file to exclude those paths e.g.

```
find /full/path/to/dir -type l -print -exec readlink -f {} \; > exclude.lst
zip -r myarchive /full/path/to/dir -x@exclude.lst
```

---

<sup>1: assuming sane filenames</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Despite Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008) claiming support of `-y` for storing symbolic links, it seems to exclude them with this option on Ubuntu 20.04 for file references not included in the archive.
It seems you choices are:

- Don't use `-y` and include the actual files
- Use tar with `gzip`, e.g.

  ```bash
  tar -czvf archive.tar.gz files_to_include
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. It would seem that your proposed solution is "list all files to be included individually"? If not, please edit your post to make your intention easier to understand. Please note that the OP explicitly wants to _exclude symbolic links and the files they point to_.

Comment: @AdminBee you are correct!  I arrived here from a Google search and went straight to shreeniwas' answer which didn't work for my very different problem.  Please feel free to delete my answer.  It's probably worth removing shreeniwas' as well since not only did it give advice that failed me, but is also not an answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a more proper filter with some more commands and you can also use a bash array to avoid creating a list file.

The following script does everything in one go. It excludes:

- symlinks pointing to files
- symlinks pointing to folders containing files
- real folders that contain only symlinks

```bash
while read -r symlink ; do
    excluded+=("${symlink}")
    target="$(readlink "${symlink}")"
    if [[ -d "${target}" ]] ; then
        excluded+=("${symlink}*")
    fi
done <<< "$(find . -type l)"

while read -r dir ; do
    file_count="$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)"
    if [[ "${file_count}" -eq 0 ]] ; then
        excluded+=("${dir}*")
    fi
done <<< "$(find . -type d)"

zip -r "./archive.zip" "/directory/to/archive/" -x "${excluded[@]}"
```

The 2 while loops append paths to the "excluded" array that is fed to zip:

- The first one appends all the symlinks (pointing to files or folders)
- The second one appends real folders that don't contain files (symlinks don't count as files)

**Note:** in my case I have file names containing [brackets]. The zip command interprets them so I have to escape the opening bracket with a backslash . To do that, instead of appending `${symlink}` or `${dir}` to the array, I append `${symlink//\[/\\\[}` or `${dir//\[/\\\[}`.